# Dataset to each element in the dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a dataset that pulls names from a sql database, the data is of childrens parents. I am trying to loop over each child to get the childs information to another part of the program, This is what I have come up with so far but its not working all I am getting is ROW 0

```
 foreach (DataRow dataRow in ds.Tables["IDs"].Rows)
              {
                  string fammemberID = (ds.Tables["IDs"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString());
                  string firstnameF = (ds.Tables["IDs"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString());
                  string lastnameF = (ds.Tables["IDs"].Rows[0].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString());

                  createFile(value, firstnameF, lastnameF, fammemberID);
              }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're not accessing the data in the DataRows you're iterating though.  Change your code to this:

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in ds.Tables["IDs"].Rows) {  
    string fammemberID = dataRow[0].ToString(); 
    string firstnameF = dataRow[1].ToString(); 
    string lastnameF = dataRow[2].ToString();

    createFile(value, firstnameF, lastnameF, fammemberID);  
}
```

or even:

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in ds.Tables["IDs"].Rows) {  
    createFile(value, dataRow[1].ToString(), dataRow[2].ToString(), dataRow[0].ToString());  
}
```